# Get first value in the first row in ng repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

**View Source:**

```
<div class="well tile single-tile">
<thread></thread>
<table class="table table-hover table-striped table-clickable">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Make</th>
            <th>Model</th>
            <th>Color</th>
            <th>Doors</th>
            <th>MPG</th>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <!-- ng-repeat: car in cars -->
       <tr ng-repeat="car in cars" ng-click="car result" class="ng-scope">
        <td class="ng-binding">Toyota</td><!--{{car.Make}} -->
        <td class="ng-binding">Corolla</td><!--{{car.Model}} -->
        <td class="ng-binding">White</td>
        <td class="ng-binding">4</td>
        <td class="ng-binding">21</td><!--{{car.MPG}} -->
       </tr>
       <tr ng-repeat="car in cars" ng-click="car result" class="ng-scope">
        <td class="ng-binding">Toyota</td><!--{{car.Make}} -->
        <td class="ng-binding">Camry</td><!--{{car.Model}} -->
        <td class="ng-binding">Black</td>
        <td class="ng-binding">4</td>
        <td class="ng-binding">20</td><!--{{car.MPG}}
       </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Protractor:**
I was able to print all values in first row using

```
element.all(by.repeater('car in cars')).first().getText().then(function(text){and console.log(text)
```

and in console I saw "Toyota Corolla White 4 21" successfully.

But I want to print only the first value from first row and second row which is "Toyota". I tried using `first().get(1).getText().then(function(text)` and `first('["$index==1"]').getText()` but it's not working. My test is to verify if there is a value other than "Toyota" in first row and second row, it should fail..

Comment: If you want to print only first value, then don't use `ng-repeat`, try directly `cars[0]` or use `filter` like: `car in cars| limitTo:1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chain and extend Binding on the item.key [locators](http://www.protractortest.org/#/locators#finding-sub-elements)

```
element.all(by.repeater('car in cars')).first().element(by.binding('car.Make')).getText();
```

for all elements

```
element.all(by.repeater('car in cars')).each(function(element, index) {
    element(by.binding('car.Make')).getText().then(function(text) {
        console.log(text);
    });
}); //there might be a better way to do this
```

Comment: Thanks, the first() and last() works successfully when there are two rows as asked in my question,  but say for example if i have three rows, For ex row1: Toyota Corolla white 4 21, row2: Toyota Camry Black 4 20, row3: Toyota Prius Green 4 18).

Comment: `first() , last(), get()` are used for picking up a single element. Do you want to iterate over all them ?

Comment: For ex row1: Toyota Corolla white 4 21, row2: Toyota Camry Black 4 20, row3: Toyota Prius Green 4 18).. How can i get text for first value in Second row.. i tried using second() similar to above and it does not work.

Comment: @user7375268 i just read your comment. updated answer which iterates over all elements. let me know if it helps. ta

Comment: @user7375268 For getting make of all cars you can use 'column' to return an array of webelements with details of the make. var makeelem = element.all(by.repeater('car in cars').column('car.Make'));